# SVN externals alternative in team foundation server 2012

Tags: svn

Currently we use SVN for our source control. Because of the extra features and integration in the development environment we would like to migrate to TFS 2012.

We have a lot of portals running that are build in asp.net. Within our portal we use a lot of standard components. Currently all portals use the same code base. This means that whenever we change something in the shared codebase it is (whenever a portal is published) automatically distributed. We are very used to this way of working and we know there is a risk of breaking code in other portals. Though, publishing changes in all other portals would cost way to much time. So to do this we use externals in SVN.

I would really like to keep this functionality up and running. So my question is, is there a way to create a external like system in SVN or is there a realy good way that works just as efficient to replace this functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestion in the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

If you download the "Everything" package and look in "All Guides" zip and have a read of "Advanced Version Control Guide".

Pages 5-19 (Version 2.1) cover Managing Shared Resources, there's a lot there and summarising it all for Stack Overflow will probably do the Ranger's an injustice, so I'll just point you there.

Answer (score -1):

Bottom line: No TFS does not have an equivalent to "svn:externals".

Code Sharing is BAD and leads to code duplication and not code reuse. Be dependant on compiled code instead.

You should be dependant only on the "output" of the shared library and not on the source files. As to scenarios, I can think of no scenarios where it is advisable to share source files between products/solutions.

The reason being is that things can get complicated an unwieldy very quickly. What if you have move than one dependant to a shared library that all make changed to the same code and they alternately break each other. The only way around that is to start branching your common code into the other projects which now adds a level of complexity and integration that will never get handled in the long run and you will end up with three or more versions of the same code base over time.

What you should do is have a single core component that is changed and build to produce output. This output can then be pulled on demand into the other projects that depend on those changes or not. This results in fewer breakages, better architecture and less technical debt.

You can even introduce NuGet into the equation using either a hosted on in-house server to publish your common component and notify each of the consumers when a new version is available.

Comment: I completely agree with you though I am now in a organisation that works like this and changing this for many portals is not currently an option. We want to migrate it in the future.

Comment: Forking is not the same thing as being able to access the source code! You *need* source code either for being able to debug though it or being able to build it on a different platform or with special features activated. "svn:externals" does not require write-access, so it does not imply a fork or a duplication of source code. "Publishing" built binaries or publishing source code is nearly the same thing, appart from the lack of flexibility and ease of use in the former case. The question is perfectly valid and still unanswered : does TFS provide an equivalent to SVN's "external" property ?

Comment: You don't need the source code to debug you just need symbols. TFS will create indexed symbols as part of a build and store them in a symbols store. You can then add this store to Visual Studio and it will always load the correct code for debugging.

Comment: For C# - yes, as a general rule you are right. There are cases when the code doesn't get compiled, for example scripts, so something similar to svn:externals would make life much easier.

Comment: Having an easy life and doing the right thing are often mutually exclusive. I would expect a professional developer to do the right thing even if it makes his/her life harder.

Comment: Microsoft developed MsBuild to make life easier so you don't have to implement your build logics in C#, or C++, or C, or Assembler, or machine codes

Comment: I want an easy life too, however shared source leads to pain and suffering. It is the dark side..