# Alternative to svn's external feature in TFS

Tags: tfs

My employer is forcing tfs down on my teams head, we have been using cc.net with nant, svn, and have been very fond of this setup. We have a couple of issues we hope to get answered, otherwise we see a 3 party dll nightmare. We have a Hugh folder of dll, lib and tools like sandcastle, wix etc. So when we release our software, the documentation is build automatically, and the setup is build etc. Today my team handle this with a common folder we call z: drive. That folder is part of the cc.net build and is checked out before a project build can be done. Can I do this with tfs, and can someone provide an example please?

```
c:\tfs\z-drive (in cc.net build we run a ‘subst z: c:\tfs\z-drive’ so we all have the same path)    
c:\tfs\projects\pro1_c++ (run checkout on c:\tfs\z-drive and subst, refernece -> z:\logging.lib; z:\message.dll)
c:\tfs\projects\pro2 c++ (run checkout on c:\tfs\z-drive and subst cmd above, , refernece -> z:\collection.dll)
c:\tfs\projects\pro3 c# (run checkout on c:\tfs\z-drive and subst cmd above, , refernece -> z:\collection.dll)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN externals alternative in team foundation server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400532/svn-externals-alternative-in-team-foundation-server-2012)

Comment: I have seen that, but if i understand that correctly, it leave me with a nightmare, when we are to maintain this setup. We would keep the z-drive setup if that is possible in tfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using external link in source is not a good idea. It creates lot of side effects. Better you depends on compiled code. Since your projects are C++, C# based I hope you also use Visual Studio for development. Package and publish your compiled code using NuGet to a private NuGet server and then consume those published packages in all the dependent projects.